# Taskbar behaviour for Swing Application

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing Application that currently has the feature `setAlwaysOnTop(true);` and is docked to the top of the screen.

Now i can't find a way for other windows (Browser, IDE) to maximize in respect of my application.

To make myself clearer here is a picture:
[image: Visual of my problem]

As you see, currently the maximized window is behind my Application.
I don't want other applications to expand behind my application; just like maximizing a browser won't expand it past the Windows taskbar.

How can i realize the desired behaviour with JAVA?

If not possible directly with/in Java, are there other ways to achieve this?

N.B.: The App only has to work on Windows 7.

I guess the reason for my lack of search results was my inability to describe this behaviour. Any hints would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So you are asking: "*how can I make another application show on top of the one that I specifically configure to be **always** on top?*" - I guess the answer is: don't make your application be on top of everything else.

Comment: No, not on top. "How can i stop another application from maximizing past my window." I.E. If you maximize your Browser, the Windows taskbar stays visible and the Browser does not expand behind the Windows taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

It is called an [Application Desktop Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The system prevents other applications from using the desktop area used by an appbar

Which is very Windows-specific, making it difficult in pure Java.

Perhaps [jdeskbar](https://code.google.com/p/jdeskbar/) could be an option if you really have to do this in Java and not a more "Windowsy" language

**EDIT:** According to the jDeskBar project wiki, the current release is broken. Maybe it can be picked apart?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into it and report back